# Geoserver get UTFGrid in Zoom, X, Y format

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, utfgrid

I am trying to overlap an UTF grid on a WMS layer in order to interact with it. As front end library I am using leaflet and the layers are served by GeoServer.

Now, I found some Leaflet plugins that are able to handle the UTFGrids, the problem is that they accept as input an URL formatted in this way:

http:///layer/z/x/y.json

Is there a way to get my UTF grid using this template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not try, but you should be able to use the internal GeoWebCache TMS service, even without actual caching, by setting:

- metatiling factor to 1
- disable caching on all zoom level (but the first one, there is no way to disable it for all zoom levels)
- "caching" only in UTFGRID format

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. I tried your solution. The problem is that I get this kind of answer from geoserver:

Coverage [minx,miny,maxx,maxy] is [271, 191, 272, 191, 8], index [x,y,z] is [132, 91, 8]

The url that I am using is the following:

http:/server_address/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/layer_name@EPSG:4326@application/json;type=utfgrid/8/132/91.json

And the HTTP answer that I get is 404